# C#: Diagnostic tools not showing garbage collection but normal runtime does

Tags: c#, memory, diagnostics

## Problem

I am trying to diagnose a potential memory leak/problem in my code. Using the memory diagnostic tools with all other options unset, the memory usage looks normal, but there are no incidents of garbage collection shown (i.e. no yellow spikes). The most confusing part is the normal runtime (no diagnostics tools) shows garbage collection, even while running on a Release configuration.

### My Theory

- The diagnostics tools also report that it, "Could not create manifest file for diagsession, VS will not be able to reopen this session."

  - Perhaps some other capabilities are failing due to this?

I am new to using the diagnostics tools, so I apologize for any novice oversights.